# Copy Javadoc comments

Tags: java, javadoc

I am doing some homework practicing the `Model-View-Controller` design pattern. In this design pattern in many cases the same method is being called through many classes

```
(Controller#foo() -> another_class1#foo() -> another_class2#foo() -> another_class_3#foo()).
```

My question is about `javadoc`.
I would want to comment `foo()` only once in the Controller class and in the rest of classes make a "getter" of the comments I made in `Controller of foo()`.
I have already tried `@see` and `@link`, but these only provide links to `Controller#foo()`, I would want to COPY the comments I have in `Controller#foo()`.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't really. You want to refer to the single source. Repeating the same thing in multiple places only adds to thecnoie level.

Comment: Oops, 'the noise level'.